# Pattern for a specified character

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

I need to extract name from a big data pouch .

```
$frame = '\"Amy Dardomba\":1,\"Kisb Muj Lorence\":1,\"Apkio Ronald\":1,....
```

there are more than 200-300 names which i have to put in array .

i tried ,

```
    preg_match_all('#\/"(.*)\/":1#',$frame,$imn);
print_r($imn);
```

but it doesnt works . Please help me .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That data looks like some bastardised JSON to me. Assuming the format of your code is the same all the way as above, try this:

```
// Two pass approach to interpollate escape sequences correctly
$toJSON = '{"json":"{'.$frame.'}"}';
$firstPass = json_decode($toJSON, TRUE);
$secondPass = json_decode($firstPass['json'], TRUE);

// Just get the keys of the resulting array
$names = array_keys($secondPass);

print_r($names);
/*
  Array
  (
      [0] => Amy Dardomba
      [1] => Kisb Muj Lorence
      [2] => Apkio Ronald
      ...
  )
*/
```

[See it working](http://codepad.org/wFQzwiRo)

Answer (score 0):

`\/` will match `/` character but you need to match `\` so use `\\` instead :

```
preg_match_all('#\\"(.*?)\\":1#',$frame,$imn);
```

Also added a `?` for non-greedy regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = '\"Amy Dardomba\":1,\"Kisb Muj Lorence\":1,\"Apkio Ronald\":1';
preg_match_all('#"([a-zA-Z\x20]+)"#', stripslashes($input), $m);
```

look in `$m[1]`